# Simplify NOT IN query

Tags: mysql

This is the movies table:
[image: movies table]

And this is the results table of the query:
[image: results table]

The query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.movieID, m.title,s.scheduleDateTime, tf.theaterFeatureID, s.scheduleID, m.releasedDate
FROM theater_feature AS tf 
LEFT JOIN schedule AS s ON s.theaterFeatureID = tf.theaterFeatureID 
INNER JOIN movie AS m ON tf.movieID = m.movieID 
WHERE (s.scheduleDateTime > '2014-10-24' OR s.scheduleDateTime IS NULL)
    AND (tf.theaterFeatureID 
        NOT IN ( SELECT s1.theaterFeatureID FROM schedule AS s1 
                WHERE s1.theaterFeatureID = tf.theaterFeatureID 
                AND s1.scheduleDateTime <= '2014-10-24') )
ORDER BY m.releasedDate, s.scheduleDateTime
```

I'm having problems with simplifying this query because it's too slow.
What it does is:

- it displays the movies with schedules on a specific date (but not current or hasn't passed yet, in this example, it's '2014-10-24'), and if a movie doesn't have a schedule yet (or NULL), it should be included also.
- But if the movie passes the first qualification (the movies with schedules on '2014-10-24', or a movie doesn't have a schedule yet or IS NULL), but has a schedule on a date that has passed already, that movie shouldn't be included.
  In short, the query is for coming soon movies.

In the table, the movies "Maps to the Stars" and "The Maze Runner" is not included in the result table since they have a schedule that has passed already. The query is fine already but I want it to be simplified, if possible, replace the NOT IN.

I know it sounds complicated but I really need to figure this out already. I'd really appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: Post your sample data on sqlfiddle.com

Comment: here's the sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa4e8/6/0

Answer (score 0):

See if the ID exists rather than doing a `NOT IN`.

Instead of:

```
 NOT IN ( SELECT s1.theaterFeatureID FROM schedule AS s1 
                WHERE s1.theaterFeatureID = tf.theaterFeatureID 
                AND s1.scheduleDateTime <= '2014-10-24')
```

Do:

```
 NOT EXISTS( SELECT s1.theaterFeatureID FROM schedule AS s1 
                WHERE s1.theaterFeatureID = tf.theaterFeatureID 
                AND s1.scheduleDateTime <= '2014-10-24')
```

**EDIT** Full query, for clarity

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.movieID, m.title,s.scheduleDateTime, 
                tf.theaterFeatureID, s.scheduleID, m.releasedDate
FROM theater_feature AS tf 
       LEFT JOIN schedule AS s ON s.theaterFeatureID = tf.theaterFeatureID 
       INNER JOIN movie AS m ON tf.movieID = m.movieID 
    WHERE s.scheduleDateTime > '2014-10-24'
         AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT s1.theaterFeatureID FROM schedule AS s1 
                WHERE s1.theaterFeatureID = tf.theaterFeatureID 
                AND s1.scheduleDateTime <= '2014-10-24') 
    ORDER BY m.releasedDate, s.scheduleDateTime
```

And adding indexes on the columns that are being queried may also help.

Comment: Doesn't really simplify, but it should speed up the query.

Comment: when i replaced the NOT IN to NOT EXISTS, it has an error in SQL Syntax near 'EXISTS.....'.

Comment: @user3815765, I added the entire query for you to look at.  There was one other piece that needed to be removed, which I thought was implied.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.movieID, m.title,s.scheduleDateTime, tf.theaterFeatureID, s.scheduleID, m.releasedDate
FROM theater_feature AS tf 
LEFT JOIN schedule AS s ON s.theaterFeatureID = tf.theaterFeatureID 
INNER JOIN movie AS m ON tf.movieID = m.movieID 
WHERE s.scheduleDateTime > '2014-10-24'
ORDER BY m.releasedDate, s.scheduleDateTime
```

Why you use `NOT IN` condition, its already get those data which grater than scheduleDateTime, using this condition `WHERE s.scheduleDateTime > '2014-10-24'`

Comment: but if a movie has a schedule that had passed already even if it has a schedule that is > '2014-10-24', that movie shouldn't be included

Comment: can you post your table structure

Answer (score 0):

I suggest 2 things:

1. don't use DISTINCT; in your test data this does not appear to be necessary
2. Add an index on schedule.scheduleDateTime

   CREATE INDEX ix_scheduleDateTime ON schedule (scheduleDateTime)
   ;

Then either of the following will produce the same result (from your test data at sqlfiddle):

```
SELECT
      m.movieID
    , m.title
    , s.scheduleDateTime
    , tf.theaterFeatureID
    , s.scheduleID
    , m.releasedDate
FROM theater_feature AS tf
      LEFT JOIN schedule AS s
                  ON s.theaterFeatureID = tf.theaterFeatureID
      INNER JOIN movie m
                  ON tf.movieID = m.movieID
WHERE (s.scheduleDateTime > '2014-10-24'  OR s.scheduleDateTime IS NULL)
      AND tf.theaterFeatureID
          NOT IN (
                SELECT
                      s1.theaterFeatureID
                FROM schedule AS s1
                WHERE s1.theaterFeatureID = tf.theaterFeatureID
                      AND s1.scheduleDateTime <= '2014-10-24'
          )
ORDER BY
      m.releasedDate, s.scheduleDateTime
;
```

.

```
SELECT
      m.movieID
    , m.title
    , s.scheduleDateTime
    , tf.theaterFeatureID
    , s.scheduleID
    , m.releasedDate
FROM theater_feature AS tf
      LEFT JOIN schedule AS s
                  ON s.theaterFeatureID = tf.theaterFeatureID
      INNER JOIN movie AS m
                  ON tf.movieID = m.movieID
WHERE (s.scheduleDateTime > '2014-10-24'  OR s.scheduleDateTime IS NULL)
      AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT NULL
            FROM schedule AS s1
            WHERE s1.theaterFeatureID = tf.theaterFeatureID
                  AND s1.scheduleDateTime <= '2014-10-24'
      )
ORDER BY
      m.releasedDate, s.scheduleDateTime
;
```

At sqlfiddle the execution plans look the same

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6db9f4/7
- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6db9f4/7/0
- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6db9f4/7/1